# Remove text from textarea line by line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I did a code that removes the text on the textarea line by line. However it seems it is not working it removes the first line after that the third line and repeat again any one help me please this is the code i tried:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#remove').click(function(){
var textareavalue = $('#sometext').val().split("\n");

for(i=0; i < textareavalue.length;i++)
{
$('span').append('<br />Remove: '+textareavalue[i]);    
textareavalue.splice(0, 1);
$('#sometext').val(textareavalue.join("\n"));
}


});
});
</script>
</head> 







<textarea cols="40" rows="10" id="sometext"></textarea>
<br />
<button id="remove">Remove</button>
<br />
<span><span/>
```

Comment: what does php has to do with this?

Comment: Well go and ask stackoverflow why they suggested PHP :)

Comment: boots are foolish, humans are not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use index `0` like this:

```
$('span').append('<br />Remove: '+textareavalue[0]);
```

This is because the previous displayed element is removed with `splice`, so your next line is again at the first position.

Also change your loop condition, because your `length` is decreasing with this `split`:

```
while(textareavalue.length)
```

You should also give an `id` to our `span`, because other `span` tags may exist on your page (or in future).

It would be good to clear your `span` contents on every click, so it only shows the result of the last removal operation.

And it would probably be nice to not have it happen all at the same time, because then you just see the end-result. You could could use a timer like this:

**HTML**

```
<textarea cols="40" rows="10" id="sometext">
</textarea>
<br />
<button id="remove">Remove</button>
<br />
<span id="out"><span/>
```

**JS**

```
function removeLine() {
    if ($('#sometext').val().replace(/\n$/, '').length === 0) {
        // nothing to do
        return;
    }
    var textareavalue = $('#sometext').val().split("\n");
    // log line that will be removed
    $('#out').append('<br />Remove: '+textareavalue[0]); 
    // remove line
    textareavalue.splice(0, 1);
    $('#sometext').val(textareavalue.join("\n"));
    // remove next line with delay
    setTimeout(removeLine, 200);
}

$(function(){
    $('#remove').click(function(){
        // clear log
        $('#out').html('');
        setTimeout(removeLine, 200);
    });
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/acgjydd2/).

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0, l = textareavalue.length; i < l; i++) {
    $('span').append('<br />Remove: '+textareavalue[0]);    
    textareavalue.splice(0, 1);
    $('#sometext').val(textareavalue.join("\n"));
}
```

Comment: THank you, your answer almost fit however when i try I'm getting a problem the loop does not stop for example if i put test1,test2,test3,test4 the result is Remove: test1
Remove: test2
Remove: test3
Remove: test4
Remove: test1
Remove: test2
Remove: test3
Remove: test4

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because of using splice() method the array itself updating with new data and loop is also repeating on same array. Change the i value to 0 inside the loop.